# Get specific column data from all tables in Big Query datasets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get latest created date from each table in big query dataset. Assuming I have datasets with the name myDataset and having 10 tables: table_a, table_b, table_c, etc... (and lets say each table have created_date column)
I know I can do that for each table using:

```
SELECT MAX(created_date) 
FROM `myDataset.myTable`
```

But, can I do that in single query for the whole table in myDataset?
I just need the output something like this and insert it to the new table:

```
| table_name | created_date                   |
|------------|--------------------------------|
| table_a    | 2020-09-20 17:50:22.321449 UTC |
| table_b    | 2020-09-20 17:50:22.321449 UTC |
| table_c    | 2020-09-20 17:50:22.321449 UTC |
```

Already tried:

```
mydataset.__TABLES__
```

and INFORMATION_SCHEMA

but I think creation_time and last_modified_time provided is not the one I'm looking for.

Found a way to get a list of all tables or columns in datasets using

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM `project_id`.myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY table_name'
```

Still not sure how to join/union this one without specifying each table.

Edit: ended up iterate each table in python to get MAX(created_date), don't know if it possible using only SQL

Comment: I iterate to get MAX(created_date) using programming language, not sure if I can do that using only SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables have same columns(domain), you can use `Union`.

Comment: Ok I've got value for created_date column, but how to get table_name value? which reference each table name in datasets

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` like this:

```
SELECT '`table_a`' as table_name, MAX(created_date) 
FROM `table_a`
UNION ALL
SELECT '`table_b`' as table_name, MAX(created_date) 
FROM `table_b`
UNION ALL
SELECT '`table_c`' as table_name, MAX(created_date) 
FROM `table_c`
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, thank you, but is there another method without specifying each table? since I got more than 300+ tables in a single datasets. (already update my question above)